# Как проверить содержит ли строка подстроку

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, есть переменная `$message = 'Типо сообщение, попугай, чайка, 801';`

Как проверить содержит ли данная переменная допустим слово  `попугай`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strpos.php - возвращает позицию первого вхождения подстроки

Пример из документации:

```
$mystring = 'abc';
$findme   = 'a';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

// Заметьте, что используется ===.  Использование == не даст верного 
// результата, так как 'a' находится в нулевой позиции.
if ($pos === false) {
    echo "Строка '$findme' не найдена в строке '$mystring'";
} else {
    echo "Строка '$findme' найдена в строке '$mystring'";
    echo " в позиции $pos";
}
```

еще есть http://php.net/manual/ru/function.stripos.php - тоже как и  strpos возвращает позицию первого вхождения подстроки, но все это без учета регистра. Опять пример из документации:

```
$findme    = 'a';
$mystring1 = 'xyz';
$mystring2 = 'ABC';

$pos1 = stripos($mystring1, $findme);
$pos2 = stripos($mystring2, $findme);

// Конечно, 'a' не входит в 'xyz'
if ($pos1 === false) {
    echo "Строка '$findme' не найдена в строке '$mystring1'";
}

// Заметьте, что используется ===.  Использование == не даст верного 
// результата, так как 'a' в нулевой позиции.
if ($pos2 !== false) {
    echo "Нашел '$findme' в '$mystring2' в позиции $pos2";
}
```

Как пост скриптум: рекомендую ознакомиться со всеми функциями для работы со строками или хотя бы основные. Они написаны вот тут: http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.strings.php